# Javascript add parameters in setInterval

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have elements that can be clicked. The quantity of elements depends of a MySQL query.
When an element is clicked, it need to look for data every second with AJAX.
Each element has his specific answer from the database.
When expected data has arrived for one element, the function must stop for that element.

I'm able to let it work if there is one element, but don't know how to proceed if multiple elements comes from query.

```
//MYSQL QUERY

while($query->fetch())
{
<div id="<?php echo $query['id']; ?>" 
     onclick='getData("<?php echo $query['id']; ?>");'>

</div>
}
```

Js.:

```
function getData(id) {

  var x = setInterval(function(){ajaxRequest(id)}, 1000);

}

function ajaxRequest(id){

    //select response from database where ID = id
    if($data['response'] == "1")
    {
     document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "There is new data";
     clearInterval(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to store your interval ID in your DOM element:

```
elm.addEventListener("click", function() {
    elm.intervalID = setInterval(/* whatever */, 1000);
});
```

Then you can clear:

```
clearInterval(elm.intervalID);
```

Comment: Just a question: should you use the `data` properties?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just looking for the data, why no use the callback functionality of JQuery's AJAX object?

```
$.ajax("service.php")
    .done(function(data) {
         document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = data;
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I'm guessing wildly, but probably because the question isn't tagged with jQuery, nor does the OP use jQuery anywhere ?

Comment: What's this `$data['response']`?

Comment: It's an object called `$data`, a dollarsign doesn't mean jQuery is being used, even if it most likely is

Comment: @Papa I don't know this one! this `done` means when something is echoed in the php file? I'd like a quick example please

Comment: @greg `.done` is fired when the request has been complete. See my edit.

Comment: If the OP really is using an interval to catch the result of an ajax call, then this definitively is the solution, and hats off to you for understanding it.

Comment: alright, I tought it was like CRON; that it only sends back succeded not when script has been executed, but when the query founds something. this php file is looking for an answear of another user...

Comment: That's still the case but you're telling the request to listen for a return. Jquery uses the `XMLHttpRequest` object and assigns event listeners like `onload` to capture the response of the request.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. I did jump to the Jquery conclusion but I couldn't let lie that he was looping code just to get data from an AJAX call.